# Increment a date by a interval from a difference of dates - Postgres

Tags: postgresql, datetime, sql-update, intervals

Edited: Added information that date1 is a timestamp

I need to increment date but the interval is based on the difference between the date that I want to increment and another date on the table but preserving date1 hours and minutes. E.g.:

```
Create myTable
( id serial,
  date1 timestamp,
  date2 date
)
```

So, if date1 = '2020-01-10 10:30:00'and date2 = '2020-03-08' I need date1 to be '2020-03-08 10:30:00'

```
Update myTable set date1 = date1+interval (date2-date1)
```

The syntax demands single quotes between the value (i.e: date + interval '30 days'). How to wrap the result from (date2-date1) in single quotes? I tried many ways without success:

```
Update myTable set date1 = date1+interval chr(39)||cast((date2-date1) as varchar)|| ' days'|| chr(39)
Update myTable set date1 = date1+interval $$||cast((date2-date1) as varchar)|| ' days'||$$
Update myTable set date1 = date1+interval ''||cast((date2-date1) as varchar)|| ' days'||''
```

How to I do this properly?

Comment: `set date1 = date1+interval (date2-date1)` isn't it equivalent to `set date1 = date2`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot to mention that date1 is a timestamp and I need to preserve hours and minutes. Edited the question, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to set the date part of `date1` to `date2` and keep the time part:

```
update myTable
set date1 = date2 + date1::time;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f4vgJYx2eQvC9N7XguuGBU/0).